# Checking if string exists in array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array `values` declared as follows:

```
var values = Object.keys(oldvals).map(function(key) {
    return oldvals[key];
});
```

This is the contents of `values`:

```
{ '0': '0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be' }
```

Next, I am executing the following code:

```
block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
   console.log(e.to);

   if (values.indexOf(e.to) > -1) {
       console.log("FOUND")
   }

});
```

Now the `e.to` logging prints the following:

```
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
0x88c1ffdcb9d631ef66eec30e706c1baaa415d22c
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
0x014f34c3f7858c2a5171bc307922a823b658d7bd
```

clearly showing that the address I am searching for exists in `values`, however, `FOUND` is never printed. I do not understand why.

Comment: what do you see in the indexOf result? `console.log(values.indexOf(e.to))`

Comment: it prints -1 for everything

Comment: console.log(oldvals[key]) before returning it. and check manually. you may have an idea.

Comment: `map` always returns an array, which is represented in JavaScript by `[ '0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be' ]`. The question has it represented using `{ '0': '0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be' }`, which is typically reserved for representing objects. I'm not sure how you are seeing it represented like that, but generally the best way to get a cleaner representation of what is contained in a variable is to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable, null, 2))`, for variables that hold values representable by JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const obj = {'0': 'data0', '1': 'data1'},
    exist = Object.values(obj).indexOf('data1') > -1;

console.log('exist:', exist);
```

Comment: I can't use values as it says it's not defined

Comment: It don't  show on your template. I think `block.transactions.forEach(...)` before declare `var values = /**/;`, yes?

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldvals =[{ '0': 0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be }];

var transactions =[{'to':'0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be'},
{'to':'0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2b1'}, 
{'to':'0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2b2'},];


transactions.forEach( function(e) {
   console.log(e.to);

if (values.indexOf(e.to) > -1) {
   console.log("FOUND")
   }

});

output result...

0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2be
FOUND
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2b1
0x3dedc2e13c8d8f944c9c6b99c414d67f62e1a2b2
```

please attached a sample structure how oldvals and transactions look like.

Answer (score -2):

You can use underscorejs library it has many utility tools which will help you reduce your code
Have a look to that library

Comment: This does not address the question that was asked.